# How to get more experts on the site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Certain Buddhism related topics maybe connected to other areas of expertise. We need to have a way to attract people who have a good knowledge in Buddhism and also other areas. Any thoughts in getting domain experts knowledgeable in Buddhism on the site?

Comment: Some of them are on the DharmaWheel/DhammaWheel forums. I would guess that experts that already blog, participate in forums, mailing lists etc are the most likely target candidates.

Comment: Perhaps you can post to let them know about this site also.